# setContentAreaFilled() and setBorderPainted() makes my GUI lag so much

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Button extends JButton {
    public Button() {
        super();
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setBorderPainted(false);
    }

  
    public void displayPiece(Tile t) {
        if (t.getOccupiedStat() && !t.getOccupant().getCaptureStat()) {
            BufferedImage img = t.getOccupant().getImage();
            setIcon(new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(40, 40, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
        }
    }
```

this is original source code, this class basically adds images to the buttons. However, adding the "setContentAreaFilled(false); setBorderPainted(false);" displays the background image but makes it so lag. Removing this solves the issue but the background is not displayed. The background for the GUI is essential since it's a "gameboard" background

Comment: Interesting.  Edit a [mre] in your question so we can copy the code into our IDE and see why this is happening.

Comment: I made edits to the code, hopefully it helps.

Comment: What's Tile?  Your code is not runnable in an IDE.  Generally, you should read and scale all of your images before you construct the GUI.

Comment: *"hopefully it helps"* - Well, it doesn't help **enough**.  Please read the link that explains what a minimal reproducible example is ... and provide something that meets those criteria.

Comment: I'll get back to this. Thank you all for responding but for now I used a different solution. The reason I can't edit it right now because there are so many classes involved and I'm just new to java programming. So it may take a while for me to edit a reproducable example